# I was trying to find the function which satisfies $f(x)*f(y)+2=f(x)+f(y)+f(xy)$

Tags: limits, functions

I was trying to find the function which satisfies $$f(x)*f(y)+2=f(x)+f(y)+f(xy)\ ,$$ where its given that $f'(0)=0$ and $f'(1)=2$.

So what I did was partially differentiated the relation wrt $x$.
 So I got $f'(x)*f(y)=f'(x)+f'(xy)y$.
Putting $x=1$ we get 
$f'(1)*f(y)= f'(1)+f'(y)y$.
 Solving this diff equation I couldn't get the proper function.

Comment: $f(0)f(0) + 2 = f(0)+f(0)+f(0)$ so $f(0)^2 + 2 = 3f(0)$ which can be factored as $(f(0)-1)(f(0)-2) = 0$. You have either $f(0) = 1$ or $f(0) = 2$, so there's probably something wrong with your problem statement.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = g(x)+1$. Then the above equation becomes $g(x)g(y) = g(xy)$. Assuming continuity of $f(x)$ the solutions for this Cauchy Functional Equation are if the form $g(x) =|x|^c$. The given conditions imply $c=2$ so that $f(x)=x^2+1$

Answer (score 1):

From

$f(x)f(y)+2 = f(x) + f(y) + f(xy)$

setting $x=y=0$ we have

$f(0)^2 + 2 = 3f(0)$

Solving this quadratic gives $f(0)\in \{1,2 \}$. So there is no solution with $f(0)=0$.

Similarly, setting $x=y=1$ gives $f(1)^2 + 2 = 3f(1)$ and so $f(1)\in \{1,2 \}$.

If $f(0)=2$ then setting $x=0$ gives us

$2f(y)+2=f(y)+4\\ \Rightarrow f(y)=2 \space \forall y$

On the other hand, if $f(1)=1$ then setting $x=1$ gives us

$f(y)+2=2f(y)+1 \\ \Rightarrow f(y)=1 \space \forall y$

Note: the problem statement was changed after I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can solve it from an ODE! Here is a hint. Substitute $f(y)=y^2g(y)$ in your differential equation and find $g(y)$. From which then, you can find $f(y)$... plain and simple!!